# Dump array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I need to fill some array with data and dump it to the screen.
Here is the code:

```
my @a;

@a[0] = 69;
foreach $sibling ($someotherlist){
    my $cha = $sibling->{"id"} * 1;

    if (defined @a[$cha]){
        @a[$cha] = 0;
    }

    @a[$cha] = @a[$cha] + 1;
}
print Dumper(@a);
```

The problem is that it only prints $VAR1 = 69;
It should be something like:

```
$VAR1 = {
   0 => 69,
   1 => 30,
   20 => 90
}
```

Comment: You need to turn on `use strict; use warnings;`. You will then get at least one warning of `Scalar value @a[0] better written as $a[0]`

Comment: Tip: That `* 1` is rather useless

Comment: Tip: `if (defined $a[$cha]) { $a[$cha] = 0; }` can be simplified to `$a[$cha] //= 0;`. If you don't want a dependency on Perl 5.10+, you can use `$a[$cha] ||= 0;` in this case.

Comment: Tip: `$a[$cha] = $a[$cha] + 1;` can be simplified to `++$a[$cha]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always use `references` with `Data::Dumper`, so

```
print Dumper(\@a);
```

See

- http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Comment: Except he wants to get a hash when he has an array... There's insufficient information to help him with that, though.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to install [`Data::Printer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer) which can be used via its `DDP` alias from the command line as `-MDDP` or as `use DDP;` inside an application. In your case:

```
use DDP; 

... # [rest of script] 

p @a ;
```

`Data::Dumper` remains the standard but `DDP` is quite useful and easily configurable. The colours and shiny things and `p()` shortcut **:-)** make `DDP` easy to use as a "visualization aid" for data structures.

Answer (score 0):

I've become a big fan of

```
use JSON;
warn to_json(\%data,{canonical=>1,pretty=>1});
```

even though it's a mess of typing.